# Print multiple lines from a Text Document - Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a program that is trying to print multiple lines from a text document.  I have my main bash program, and I am using the line:

```
    Multlines=`</Users/$USER/Documents/text.txt`

    echo $Multlines
```

Where text.txt may look something like

```
    John
    Smith
```

but the echo prints John Smith where I want it to print it on different lines.
How do I print it out that way?

Comment: While you now have an answer to this question, it seems to me that this may be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Can you explain what you're hoping to achieve by solving this particular problem? There is almost certainly a better way than the one you're using.

Comment: @ghoti I am fairly new to bash, and I have just decided to create a text based game on bash.  I have already done a couple on C++ and other languages, but this one I decided to be more of an RPG, and I wanted to add ASCII Art but without the hassle of entering the same image over and over again in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the newline characters in the variable when printing with `echo`, you need to double quote it:

```
echo "$Multlines"
```

Comment: Also good to point out that [one should almost always quote variables in bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary).

Comment: This isn't working for me at all, it just shows up as John\nSmith

Comment: Wait never mind, it worked, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use `cat` instead of echo, assuming you had it available to you.